# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'posted'

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new to programming and recently a friend of mine gave me a project to work on in order to get myself familiar with the programming environment and language (python in this particular example).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnDWIZuWYW0 I used this video as a beginners tutorial to help me understand how i'm supposed to proceed with my personal project. the code i wrote is exactly how it is written in the video, and i get an error.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Alon Salzmann',
        'title': 'First Post',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date posted': 'September 5, 2018'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Alon Salzmann',
        'title': 'Second Post',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date posted': 'September 6, 2018'
    }
]

@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    return render_template('Home.html', posts=posts)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('About.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The code above is the python code I wrote, and the code below is the html code I wrote that involves python:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date posted }}</p>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

after running the program on both cmd and powershell (not simultaneously of course), and going to my localhost address, i got the error that appears in the title:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'posted'
```

I would love to get a good explanation as to why this has been happeninig, and how to fix this. Please remember I am a beginner and maybe need to be explained a few basic concepts at first :).

P.S. The guy's code in the video worked so I would love to understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The line `<p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date posted }}</p>` is the issue here

Replace it with  `<p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted }}</p>`

`post.date_posted` is a variable and should be same as the one in your models, And spaces between them are syntax errors(typos)

Comment: Try:  `{{ post['date posted'] }}`. Spaces are valid in key names for JSON and YAML. hence may be necessary to call the value as a `dict[keyname]` rather than using dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

Also happen to me, in other case where you got the same error but your syntaxes was right, I replace:

`{{ mycode }}`

with where it's not print something but do something:

`{% mycode %}`

And it's work.

{{ }} is used to print

{% %} is used to do instruction (for, if, ...)

Comment: You might have got the same error message, but the error itself was definitely a different one, as you can see in the previous answers.

Comment: It's more one possible answer for people who encouter the same errorless (Who is the title of the question) than an answer to the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `<p>By {{ post['author'] }} on {{ post['date posted'] }}` to make it work. it is a dict. So you have to get the values with indicies instead of calls.

Answer (score 0):

For this error message, in my case, there was an extra curly bracket character, close to a Jinja fragment call. Neither online Jinja template parsers, nor plugins, caught this - they didn't provide a meaningful error message. Had to go through line by line to see where the issue was.

Error message, when parsing the template (with the syntax error) in Python:

> expected token 'end of print statement', got ':' jinja